# shell script to read CSV missing first line

Tags: csv, sh

I'm using the following :

```
#!/bin/sh

export IFS=","

cat myfile.csv | while read a b c d e f g h i j
do
#example do
echo "a=$a"
echo "b=$b:"
echo "c=$c:"
echo "d=$d:"
echo "e=$e:"
echo "f=$f:"
echo "g=$g:"
echo "h=$h:"
echo "i=$i:"
echo "j=$j:"
done
```

to read in variables from a `CSV` file. It works quite well, only that it seems to miss off the first line of the file, why is this? can I change it to capture line one also?

Comment: the code looks fine..please post the initial 3 lines of your file..

Comment: can you provide a concrete example here ?

Comment: An example `myfile.csv` input file is at http://temp-share.com/show/dPf3gpo5W, I added some test code to the OP.

Comment: It only works if I copy and paste the CSV content from the original file (output from Mathematica) to a new txt file. To the eye the two files look identical (at least to my eye), could there be some hidden formatting going on here that causes the skip. The fie I linked above is the exact file from Mathematica.

Comment: Is it missing off the first line or the last line?

Comment: @Guru it's missing the first line.

Comment: Please confirm that there are 2 lines of data in your file? Or did I read 3 lines someplace in this thread. (I only see 2 lines). good luck.

Comment: @shellter yes  2 lines, the file link is available above too if that helps.